# How to prevent android keyboard from pushing html layout up like ios in vue?

Tags: android, html, css, vue.js

I have a vuejs app and responsive component with a picture with `CSS` `bottom: 0;`

There's also an input in the page and when I tap on input on an android phone the keyboard opens and pushes the picture up! It does not behave like that on ios phone!

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share some piece of your code or a running example using codepen or codesandbox. This way other users can help you better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: How do I prevent the soft keyboard from pushing my view up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940438/want-to-have-browser-viewport-resize-when-ios-keyboard-is-activated/55671366#55671366

Answer (score 0):

You using position relate with value minus

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).